# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "x" is not found

Tags: python, discord.py

I've been trying to develop a discord bot for a while. Whenever I try to use a command, I get that error. I'm new to python and I can't seem to find a fix to it
Here's the code:

`

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl

class music(commands.Cog):
  def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client

  @commands.command()
  async def join(self,ctx):
    if ctx.author.voice is None:
      await ctx.send("Nu esti pe un voice channel")
    voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    if ctx.voice_client is None:
      await voice_channel.connect()
    else:
      await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)

  @commands.command()
  async def disconnect(self,ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

  @commands.command()
  async def play(self,ctx,url):
    ctx.voice_client.stop()
    FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconncet_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
    YDL_OPTIONS = {'format':"bestaudio"}
    vc = ctx.voice_client

    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
      info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
      url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
      source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
      vc.play(source)

def setup(client):
  client.add_cog(music(client))
```

`

Comment: Well I don't see a command named `x` anywhere in this so the error seems correct...? What exactly is the issue?

Comment: Sorry, I meant x to be a placeholder for a command name, it could be play, join, etc. it's the same error for every command.

Comment: Cog & extension loading is asynchronous, and you're not doing it asynchronously. You should be getting an error for that though, so you probably don't have logging set up properly. For more info, read the migration guide: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html#extension-and-cog-loading-unloading-is-now-asynchronous